# Rails 3 form mongodb how create a new item with an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, model

```
class Ecard
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :family, String
  key :given, String
  key :additional, String
  key :prefix, String
  key :suffix, String

  has_many :emails

end

class Email
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument

  key :pref, Boolean
  key :email, String

end
```

in the ecards controller

```
 def new
    @ecard = Ecard.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @ecard }
    end
  end
```

and in my form

```
<%= form_for(@ecard) do |f| %>

<%= f.label t :family, :scope => :name  %><br />
<%= f.text_field :family %><br />

<%= @ecard.emails.each do |email| %>
    <%= f.fields_for email, :index => email do |e| %>
        <%= e.label :pref %>
        <%= e.check_box :pref %>
        <%= e.label :email %>
        <%= e.text_field :email %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

how to create à new email nested resources ?

Answer (score 1):

While mongomapper does not support "accepts_nested_attributes_for", the follwing works for me
with rails 3.2.7, mongo_mapper 0.11.2, mongo 1.6.4, bson 1.6.4.
Refer often to "rake routes" until the routing is correct, i.e., url_for, controller methods, etc.
Please note the hidden field for email.id and the button with the route to create a new email item.
This is just for a new item in an embedded association (you get to complete the put/update).
Hope that this helps you move forward.

-Gary

app/controllers/ecards_controller.rb

```
class EcardsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @ecard = Ecard.create
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => 'ecards/show' }
      format.json { render json: @ecard }
    end
  end

  def show
    @ecard = Ecard.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => 'ecards/show' }
      format.json { render json: @ecard }
    end
  end

end
```

app/controllers/emails_controller.rb

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @ecard = Ecard.find(params[:ecard_id])
    @ecard.emails << Email.new
    @ecard.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => 'ecards/show' }
      format.json { render json: @ecard }
    end
  end
end
```

app/views/ecards/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@ecard) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :family, :scope => :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :family %><br />

    <% @ecard.emails.each do |email| %>
        <%= f.fields_for email, :index => email do |e| %>
            <%= e.hidden_field :id, :value => email.id %>
            <%= e.label :pref %>
            <%= e.check_box :pref %>
            <%= e.label :email %>
            <%= e.text_field :email %>
            <br/>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>

<% end %>
<%= button_to 'New Email', url_for([:new, @ecard, :email]), :method => :get %>
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :ecards do
    resources :emails
end
```

Comment: thank Gary, i found this solution, see my answer, but i have another problem, with check_box. I forgot, in a second time, i think use jquery to additional email when i create or edit a ecard.